# Amazon Advertising API: Is there a way to get more than 100 results in a Report Request, or to get reports for specific campaigns, keywords etc

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

I am developing an app that handles scheduling bids for campaigns and keywords, and need to be able to get the clicks, costs, sales etc. to analyse and make suggestions.

The only way I can see to get this data is by requesting and then downloading reports (requests to `/v2/sp/{recordtype}/report`) as described here:
https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/reference/sponsored-products/2/reports

This gives a report for all campaigns/adgroups/keywords in a profile, but only returns up to 100 results. However I can't find any mention of this limit in the documentation, nor how to get the next set of results, or get results for specific campaigns etc.

Has anyone got any experience with this?

Comment: Interesting... i did not heard of such a limit yet and the only account i currently have access to doesn't have so much entities. Can you give more details on the request?

Comment: I have three profiles in the sandbox environment, each of which has dozens of test campaigns and hundreds or thousands of keywords. When I request a report for keywords or adgroups it only returns 100 results. I've tried using Postman and Node.JS, both get the same result, no matter what reportDate or metrics I use.

Comment: hm... i think this is a good question for the Advertising API technical support team.
But you need access to their JIRA ...  Ask your Amazon consultant to get access to it.